# How to override the version of dependencies without changing pom.xml

Tags: spring-boot, intellij-idea, pom.xml

Is there any way we can override the version of dependencies mentioned under `<properties>` section without changing `pom.xml`.

> ```
> <properties>
>     <lombok.version>1.18.16</lombok.version>
> </properties>
> ```

For example I want to override the lombok version.